# IBKR's 1099 Forms not what I expected

Tags: united-states, form-1099, interactive-brokers

I just received my 1099 Forms from Interactive Brokers, and there are a few things that do not line up:

- Foreign Tax Paid on 1099-DIV shows $0. I owned shares the entire year in an ETF that invests in Australian stocks, and another in Swiss stocks. I own the same ETFs in my Fidelity Brokerage account as well, and its 1099-DIV shows some Foreign Tax Paid, as I expected. Why doesn't the Interactive Brokers' 1099-DIV show any?
- Exempt-Interest Dividends shows only $50.90. I own shares in an ETF that invests in municipal bonds. In previous years when this ETF was in my Fidelity account, all of its dividends showed up in this box in my 1099-DIV. Why does my Interactive Brokers account's 1099-DIV show so little? I expected thousands of dollars here.
- Lastly, I received a 1099-MISC with $2,029.87 under Substitute Payments in Lieu of Dividends or Interest. I participate in Interactive Brokers' Security Lending Program. I assume these are the dividends paid out while some of my securities were lent out. If so, I was under the impression that Interactive Brokers was smart enough to recall lent securities right before a dividend payout so that Substitute Payments in Lieu of Dividends would stay as low as possible. Was I wrong in thinking Interactive Brokers would do this? I also paid $933.71 in margin interest last year. Since the Substitute Payments in Lieu of Dividends were reported on a 1099-MISC, shouldn't I be able to report that as self-employment income and deduct the margin interest from it?

My suspicion is that all of this mess was caused by Interactive Broker's Security Lending Program. If that's the case, all I got from that program was $79 in interest last year at the expense of a much, much higher tax bill. So, why would anyone ever sign up for this?

Comment: If you were entitled to receive $2,029.87 in dividends last year and you received $2,029.87 as Payment in Lieu of Dividends then yes, it's because your stocks were loaned out for shorting  The consequence of lending stocks for shorting is that dividends are converted to ordinary income.

Comment: @BobBaerker What about the foreign income tax credit? Is that also the reason why they don't show up either?

Comment: With regard to tax documents, I can't explain why IBKR does or doesn't do something.  I'd suggest that you call them to get clarification.

Comment: It is _not_ normal for a brokerage to ‘call back borrowed shares right before dividends are paid’ - what makes you think so?

Comment: @Aganju IBKR's own Q&A Section: https://ibkr.info/article/1838
"Do participants in the Stock Yield Enhancement Program receive dividends on shares loaned?
Stock Yield Enhancement Program shares that are lent out are generally recalled from the borrower before ex-date in order to capture the dividend and avoid payments in lieu (PIL) of dividends"

Comment: No, PIL are not self-employment income. Not all income reported on 1099-MISC is self-employment, that's why it is called MISC. If you itemize you can deduct margin interest against any investment income, including qualified dividends and long-term cap gain IF you elect on 4952.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 does that mean that that income will not be charged the 15.2% self-employment tax then? Only the regular income tax?

Comment: ALL investment income (both actual dividends and PIL, interest (received), and cap gains) is not on Schedule C or F and is not subject to the 15.3% self-employment tax. If your MAGI is over $200k single or $250k joint, these (plus some more) are subject to the 3.8% ['net investment income tax'](https://www.irs.gov/newsroom/questions-and-answers-on-the-net-investment-income-tax) added by 'Obamacare' (PPACA).